# Running a background process with your java app

Tags: java, background-process

So I have this map that has the name of an employee and their voucher amount, as its key and value.

Now, I want a specific amount to be added to the values at the first day of every new month.

I have a working code that does this, but i am looking for a way to make it better

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class VoucherManager {
    private static double newVoucher = 2500.00;
    private Map<String, Double> employeeVoucher = new TreeMap<>();
    private  LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();

    public static VoucherManager getInstance() {
        return new VoucherManager();
    }
    public void incrementVoucher() {
        employeeVoucher.put("Olatunji Oniyide", 200.00);
        employeeVoucher.put("Andrew Mbata", 500.00);
        employeeVoucher.put("Opeyemi Oniyide", 700.00);

        Set<Map.Entry<String, Double>> set = employeeVoucher.entrySet();
        int day = now.getDayOfMonth();
        if((day == 1) || (day == 2)) {
            for(Map.Entry<String, Double> map : set)
               System.out.println(map.getKey() + ":" + (map.getValue() + newVoucher));
        } else {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        VoucherManager voucher = VoucherManager.getInstance();
        voucher.incrementVoucher();
    }
    }
```

When I change the current date on my system to the first day of a new month, it does the job correctly, else it doesn't.

But this only happens when the user runs the code on the first day of the month or second. When the user runs the code on the 3rd or 4th day of the month, it throws an error.

So I want to ask if there's a way to have my app create a background process which automatically just updates the values with the new figures, even when the app is not being used.

Comment: It's not yet clear what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want this to just run forever and update the values when the first of the month passes, subsequently printing out the results? If you ran it the first and the second, you'd get the same results. Why does it matter what day it is?

Comment: i'm trying to incorporate this into a gui application. that's why i am asking if my gui app can create a background process or something that monitors the date. so that when it gets to the first day of the month, the values are being updated. even if the user of the gui app doesn't run the app on the first day or second day. if user runs the app on the third day, then viola. values updated. do you understand?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. Your program gets run when it gets run; if it's not running all the time, then there's no "increment"--it just gets your starting data and either displays unincremented or incremented values. The only way around this is to save your voucher values in a persistent store along with a last-updated date, and then when you run the program, it looks to see how many "firsts of the month" have elapsed since the last update, and performs that many increments before printing. If you want the program to run continuously and update as well, you can certainly do that too.

Comment: You're an amazing man Jerry, thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a couple different ways:

- Count the number of months that have elapsed and multiply that by the monthly increment value.
- Another option is to store the values in a lightweight database (like [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) or [sqlite](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc)), and update as needed using a scheduled job.